# XeLaTeX: Accents (with Linux Libertine font) require T1-fonts

Tags: xetex, accents, libertine

I need special characters (accents, cyrillic glyphs) in my file. Cyrillic seems to work well with Linux Libertine, but accents trigger warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/LinLibertine_R.otf(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 26.
```

Question is: how do I need to fix my code/how can I use accents in this setup (xelatex + Libertine OTF fonts) without falling back to OT1/cmr?

Here is my example file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

% General font-related definitions at the top! (Taken from
% http://www.linuxlibertine.org/fileadmin/user_upload/PDF/Libertine-XeTex-DE.pdf)
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{csquotes} % Causes some error messages?

% Load font from current working directory.
\setmainfont[
  BoldFont          = LinLibertine_RZ.otf,
  ItalicFont        = LinLibertine_RI.otf,
  BoldItalicFont    = LinLibertine_RZI.otf,
  Ligatures=TeX]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setsansfont[
  BoldFont          = LinBiolinum_RB.otf,
  ItalicFont        = LinBiolinum_RI.otf,
  BoldItalicFont    = LinBiolinum_RI.otf, % FIXME?!
  Ligatures=TeX]{LinBiolinum_R.otf}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\begin{document}
.\\
zas\'{y}pat’\\ % This is line 27.
zasypat’\\
\end{document}
```

(I have all the *.otf files in my current working directory.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Avoid loading `xunicode` (and also `xltxtra`). Instructions telling to load them are largely outdated.

Comment: And instrutions telling to load xunicode *before* fontspec are plainly wrong - even on old systems. xunicode must always be loaded after fontspec so that it can pick up the correct encoding.

Comment: I see, thanks! Without loading these two packages, accents seem to work flawlessly and without warnings.

I guess I should suggest a fix for http://www.linuxlibertine.org/fileadmin/user_upload/PDF/Libertine-XeTex-DE.pdf, from which I have taken my preambel.

Answer (score 3):

Don't load `xunicode` along with `fontspec`. Instructions telling you to do so are very outdated. Also `xltxtra` is not needed, for the same reason.

There has been a period of time when loading `xunicode` was recommended; but this was at the initial stages of development of `fontspec`. Since some years, `fontspec` loads `xunicode` at the right point, so there are two cases:

1. the call to `xunicode` comes before than `fontspec`, which will cause problems;
2. the call to `xunicode` comes later than `fontspec`, which is useless.

The conclusion is obvious. `;-)`