# lualatex: pdfx and siunitx conflict on angstrom

Tags: symbols, luatex, siunitx, pdfx

I encountered a conflict between the `siunitx` and `pdfx` packages. I had a document working, but after I added the `pdfx` package I ended up with an

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \AA unavailable in encoding TU.
```

Minimal working example (`test_angstrom.tex`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx} % Force required PDF/A-2u format

\usepackage{siunitx} % Numbers and quantities

\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\angstrom}
\end{document}
```

A file with metadata `test_angstrom.xmpdata` needs to exists. I compile the source with `lualatex`. When I remove the `pdfx` package everything works. Any idea how can I introduce the angstrom symbol to the `pdfx` package?

Comment: I get no error. Is your system up-to-date? Edit: I get it with texlive 2016, with newer it is ok.

Comment: `\AA` is not encoding specific, which might account for this issue. You could try defining the character and using that instead, as shown in a [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275558).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It was the old texlive version, thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by using an up-to-date TeX distro.